# How to get a response using cURL?

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to get a response using curl according to [this doc](https://www.seedr.cc/pulse/api-doc/#how-to-use). But I'm new to cURL/REST and don't have an idea how to do that.

For an example there is this code in the doc that says it returns a list of folders

`curl -X GET -u "email:password" https://www.seedr.cc/rest/folder` ,

but when I try it in PHP it doesn't work. how can I do this ->

**Edit : it seems this is a command line curl . I tried it with command line and it works, but I need to know how to use this in a PHP script .**

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed us your PHP code, obviously removing any sensitive data.

Comment: php curl or command line curl? your code shows the latter

Comment: @TommyBs Updated the question , thanks

Comment: @nogad yes it seems this is command line code and I need to how to use it with php curl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need use curl. You can do it directly in php.

```
$url="https://www.seedr.cc/rest/folder"

$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("$username:$password")
    )
));
$data = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

Comment: file_get_contents with just an url ==> 401 Unauthorized, but file_get_contents with just an url + user + password ==> it's ok ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This is an  example of how to use cURL with php. You can use the curl_setopt function to set and change the options to suit your peculiar case. Some of them are actually optional. [You can check the table here to get a full list of what they do](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.curl-setopt.php)

```
    $durl = "https://www.seedr.cc/rest/folder?email=$password" ;
    $ch =  curl_init()  ;
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $durl);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
    $dinf = curl_exec ($ch); 
    if(!curl_errno($ch) ){
        echo $dinf ;

    }else{
        echo curl_error($ch) ;
    }
```